# class mediator logs are not reflecting in Wso2 esb

Tags: log4j, wso2, apache-commons-logging, wso2-esb

Hi am working with WSO2 ESB 4.7.0

I have created a simple proxy and used class mediator to add couple of nums as shown below.

```
    <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="Add_class"
       transports="https http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="messagetype"
                   value="application/json"
                   scope="axis2"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="ContentType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
         <property name="Maths" expression="//Maths/text()"/>
         <property name="Eng" expression="//Eng/text()"/>
         <property name="Hindi" expression="//Hindi/text()"/>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="LogLocation" value="Add_class"/>
            </log>
         <class name="org.example.mediator.MailEsb"/>
         <filter xpath="get-property('ToatalMarks')=''">
            <then>
               <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                  <format>
                     <ResponseJSON xmlns="">
                        <Body>
                           <Datalist>ToatalMarks Not Found</Datalist>
                        </Body>
                        <Status>404</Status>
                     </ResponseJSON>
                  </format>
                  <args/>
               </payloadFactory>
               <log level="custom">
                  <property name="LogLocation" value="Add_class"/>
                  <property name="ToatalMarks" expression="get-property('ToatalMarks')"/>
               </log>
               <send/>
            </then>
            <else>
               <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                  <format>
                     <ResponseJSON xmlns="">
                        <Body>
                           <Datalist>ToatalMarks of the subjets is</Datalist>
                           <Sum>$1</Sum>
                        </Body>
                        <Status>404</Status>
                     </ResponseJSON>
                  </format>
                  <args>
                     <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('ToatalMarks')"/>
                  </args>
               </payloadFactory>
               <log level="custom">
                  <property name="LogLocation" value="Add_class"/>
                  <property name="ToatalMarks" expression="get-property('ToatalMarks')"/>
               </log>
               <send/>
            </else>
         </filter>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

class:

```
package org.example.mediator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory;
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement;
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMNode;
import org.apache.axiom.om.OMText;
import org.apache.axiom.om.xpath.AXIOMXPath;
import org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPBody;
import org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPFactory;

import org.apache.synapse.ManagedLifecycle;
import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext; 
import org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfiguration;
import org.apache.synapse.core.SynapseEnvironment;
import org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator;
import org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2MessageContext; 

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;


public class MailEsb extends AbstractMediator implements
ManagedLifecycle 
{ 

    public boolean mediate(MessageContext synCtx) { 

        log.info("LogLocation = "+getClass().getName()+",ProxyName = "+synCtx.getProperty("proxy.name")+
                ",Usercode = "+synCtx.getProperty("usercode")+",Clientid = "+synCtx.getProperty("clientid")+
                    ",Position = START");
           try {  
        String Eng=""+synCtx.getProperty("Eng");
        String Maths=""+synCtx.getProperty("Maths");
        String Hindi=""+synCtx.getProperty("Hindi");

        int T= Integer.parseInt(Eng) + Integer.parseInt(Maths) + Integer.parseInt(Hindi);

        synCtx.setProperty("ToatalMarks", T);
        log.info("LogLocation = "+getClass().getName()+", Total of all the subjects is= " +T);
           }

           catch (Exception e) {
                log.info( "LogLocation = "+getClass().getName()+", mail sending exception: "+e+e.getMessage());

                       }
        return true;

    }
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void init(SynapseEnvironment arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    }
```

I have defined logs in my class code to reflect in my Wso2 esb server but failing to do so....

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try adding the mediator class in log4j.properties file?

Comment: Thanks,got it i have changed class level to INFO in Configure --> Logging in management console.

Comment: Please mark the above answer as the correct answer if got your problem resolved.

Comment: There is an example how to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aw5TaSy4k_c&t=27m31s

Answer (score 0):

You also need to change your class with the proper logger,

"private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MailEsb.class);"

So you can properly manage your logs and also your exceptions should be

log.error not log.info