# Logging is not functioning properly after changing Logging Configuration via managemnt console in WSO2 EI 6.5.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have developed API which call the class mediator via sequence in WSO2 EI 6.5.0. Initially API logs are getting printed except class mediator logs in Server log.

To enable logs for class mediator as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451723/class-mediator-logs-are-not-reflecting-in-wso2-esb), I logged into management console `Home> Configure> Logging` section and went to section `Configure Log4J Loggers` , searched log keyword whatever i added inside class mediator to find out class mediator and changed class level to `Debug`

[image: management console]

post this change, nothing is printed when i invoke service via postman, but API response getting. I just restarted server, post this management console url also not getting printed in server logs.

Below is the management console logging configuration image for reference.

[image: total page]

Class Mediator:

```
package com.abc.in;
import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext; 
import org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator;
import org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2MessageContext;
/*import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;*/


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class DuplicateHeadersMediator extends AbstractMediator {

    // private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(DuplicateHeadersMediator.class);
    public boolean mediate(MessageContext messageContext) {
         log.info("DuplicateHeadersMediator called********** : " );
         trace.info("trace DuplicateHeadersMediator called********** :");
        org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext axis2MessageContext = ((Axis2MessageContext) messageContext)
                .getAxis2MessageContext();
       
        Map excessHeaders = (Map) axis2MessageContext.getProperty("EXCESS_TRANSPORT_HEADERS");
        log.info("excessHeaders : " + excessHeaders.entrySet());
        trace.info("trace excessHeaders : " + excessHeaders.entrySet());
        Map transportHeaders = (Map) axis2MessageContext.getProperty("TRANSPORT_HEADERS");
        log.info("transportHeaders : " + transportHeaders.entrySet());
        trace.info("trace transportHeaders : " + transportHeaders.entrySet());
        if (excessHeaders.size() != 0 && transportHeaders.size() != 0) {
            for (Object key : transportHeaders.keySet()) {
                addPropertiesForExcessHeaders((String)key,excessHeaders,messageContext);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Add extra properties to the synapse message context for duplicated headers.
    private void addPropertiesForExcessHeaders(String headerName, Map excessHeaders, MessageContext messageContext) {
        if (excessHeaders.get(headerName) != null) {
            ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList) excessHeaders.get(headerName);
            if (list.size() > 0) {
                int i = 2;
                for (String value : list) {
                    String propName = headerName + i;
                    messageContext.setProperty(propName, value);
                    log.info("propName : " + propName);
                    trace.info("trace propName : " + propName);
                    i += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

API:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/readcookiesapi" name="ReadCookiesAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="ReadCookiesAPI" value="is called *****"/>
            </log>
            <sequence key="HeaderMediatorCall_Sequecne"/>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="$trp:test" name="test1"/>
                <property expression="$ctx:test2" name="test2"/>
                <property expression="$ctx:test3" name="test3"/>
            </log>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Sequence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="HeaderMediatorCall_Sequecne" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="HeaderMediatorCall_Sequecne" value="B4 *****"/>
    </log>
    <class name="com.abc.in.DuplicateHeadersMediator"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="HeaderMediatorCall_Sequecne" value="after *****"/>
    </log>
</sequence>
```

Kindly clarify my doubts mentioned below.

1. how can I recover default logging mechanism since this change made product logging weird, so that artifacts like API, Sequence etc and server logs i'll get properly
2. why class mediator logs are not getting printed initially or how can i get those class mediators log in wso2 ei server 6.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used `java.util.logging.Logger` to reflect logger inside class mediator. Still not sure why `org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory` not printing anything in log.

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ParseEmailBody extends AbstractMediator {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ParseEmailBody.class.getName());


public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) {
logger.info("===Inside ParseEmailBody Class Mediator===");

return true;
}
```

Comment: If anyone else is referring to this, this is not recommended. You Shouldn't be using different logging frameworks within the class mediators. In order to simplify this the Abstract class already provides you with a logger instance.

Answer (score 1):

When you extend [AbstractMediator](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/mediators/AbstractMediator.java) you should already have an instance of the logger for you to use. Check [here](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/mediators/AbstractMediator.java#L53). So you don't have to instantiate a new Logger. You can simply use the existing logger.

Comment: Hi @ycr,
Thanks for your response, I just installed fresh WSO2 EI 6.5.0 in my machine(windows 10) .As per your suggestion reused log and removed instantiation of new logger inside class mediator, Post this also class mediator logs are not getting printed , remaining logs like API, sequence only get printed. Is there any other change required in log4j.properties file to enable class mediator log?

Comment: @Justin Typically it would be automatically picked up. If not you can add the Log configurations of your class mediator to the log4j.properties file.

Comment: Hi @ycr,
Thanks for your suggestion, if possible pls share some ref link to make changes in log4j.properties file for enabling class mediator log eg log4j.logger.packagename.classname=ERROR, CARBON_LOGFILE, CARBON_MEMORY

Comment: @Justin Try adding this line to your log4j.properties file. `log4j.logger.packagename.classname=INFO`